# How do I show errors for a new front end entry form?

Tags: variable, validation, frontend-form, error-handling

I'm using a front end form so logged-in users can create a new entry ("post") or edit an existing entry. Here's the controller for figuring out whether it's a new or existing entry:

```
{# Get the entry being edited from the url parameter #}
{% set entry_id = craft.app.request.getParam('id') %}
{% if entry_id %}
  {% set post = craft.entries({
    id: entry_id,
    status: null
  }).one() %}
{% else %}
  {% set post = null %}
{% endif %}
```

For the form fields, I'm using Twig partials and `with { 'entry' : post }`.

This works great for editing a post, and I can create a new post as long as I enter the info that Craft expects. However, there are some required fields, and I want to show error messages when those fields are missing, rather than the post silently failing to be created.

Per the [entry form documentation](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/examples/entry-form.html), I'm including the suggested macro and this chunk of code with my required `headline` field:

```
{% if entry is defined %}
  {{ errorList(entry.getErrors('headline')) }}
{% endif %}
```

**Desired behavior:** 
if I try to save a new entry that's missing a headline, I should get the error message for that field.

**Actual behavior:**
This gives me a runtime error: `Impossible to invoke a method ("getErrors") on a null variable.`

I've tried setting `post = {}` for an empty object, but Twig seems to see that as an array and can't invoke `getErrors` on that either.

How should I go about addressing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to a teammate, got this working!

Needed to change the conditional wrapping my error messages from

```
{% if entry is defined %}
```

to

```
{% if entry is defined and entry is not null %}
```